# Redshift alter numeric column with data

Tags: amazon-redshift, ddl

I have a table in Redshift  which has rate column and date column. the rate column has numeric data type with (18,2). I want change that to (18,4). since this column already contains data  I could not alter the column. Is there anyway to do that without losing data. here is the syntax I'm using and the error I got.
This is the Syntax

```
ALTER TABLE pricetable 
   ALTER COLUMN product_price 
   TYPE numeric(18,4);
```

this is the Error

> Invalid operation: cannot alter column "product_price" of relation "pricetable" [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=500310]**

Comment: Why would altering the column not work? Doesn't https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Ftk7VqEpnPL6b8GkZRRJS/0 do what you want?

Comment: Why do you think you can't change the data type? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Comment: I'm using same syntax but instead of SET DATA TYPE I used TYPE only. changing that also did not work. my table is in redshift . does it effect ?

Comment: Could you show us your SQL, the error messages and/or any other results? We're now just guessing what's going on

Comment: Redshift is not postgresql. You should change the question tag if your question is about redshift.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my question first , can you help me to fix the issue now?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html). There are multiple reasons why this might fail. The column might have a default value, or its compression type is incompatible with changing the data type.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why this could be failing.  I'll use the Redshift documentation on this to show many:

> ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE new_data_type A clause that changes the
> size of a column defined as a VARCHAR data type. Consider the
> following limitations:
>
> You can't alter a column with compression encodings BYTEDICT,
> RUNLENGTH, TEXT255, or TEXT32K.
>
> You can't decrease the size less than maximum size of existing data.
>
> You can't alter columns with default values.
>
> You can't alter columns with UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, or FOREIGN KEY.
>
> You can't alter columns within a transaction block (BEGIN ... END).
> For more information about transactions, see Serializable isolation.

This leads to the following questions / possibilities:

- What is the encoding of the column product_price?
- Does the existing data fit in 18,4?  You lost 2 digits before the decimal point - you may need 20,4.
- Does product_price have a default value?
- Are there constraints on the column product_price or is it a key?
- Are you in autocommit mode or are you managing your transaction block when executing? (Run "END; ;" as one block)

Depending on what issue you are encountering there are ways to work around them.  Like autocommit mode and adding the new column, renaming old & new columns, and dropping the old etc.

Comment: Redshift doesn’t let you change column type, the command to do so is only their to change varchar length size, no other type can be affected

Answer (score 1):

The issue here may be related to the data type. The clause only supports altering the size of a VARCHAR data type. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html